# OpenCv for c++ on ubuntu is not getting installed

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, opencv-contrib

Assalamualaikum

[I followed this article from top to bottom](http://www.codebind.com/cpp-tutorial/install-opencv-ubuntu-cpp/?fbclid=IwAR2h1Rqd-YNcyiILLzKr3MZMlC-tleX_6mp_a097KPWSRl5xY_DRGV_-DI4)
But when I executed -

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
```

an error message  showed up -'Package opencv4 was not found in the pkg-config search path'

However, there exists a folder named opencv4 in -/usr/local/include.

(I want to convert my python image filter files into c++ image filters .
I am using vscod and I din't find any extension for c++ there)

Comment: I'm not sure installation questions are a great fit for stackoverflow.  Perhaps this would be better for askubuntu or superuser?

Comment: Extremely  sorry for the inconvenience. I am very new to all these.Din't know any of these sites